# Why $\nu_ee^-$ has a larger scattering cross-section than $\nu_\mu e^-$ cross-section?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos, weak-interaction

Why is the scattering cross-section of $\nu_\mu$'s with the electron $e^-$ much smaller than the scattering cross-section of $\nu_ee^-$ scattering both of which take place through charged current weak interaction?

Answer (score 2):

For $\nu_e$, there are the following three diagrams. For $\nu_\mu$, there is only the first one.

[image]